# Actors WCF Service - Client code using WCF

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-actor

I have an Actor Service which uses WCF:

```
[assembly: WcfActorRemotingProvider(RemotingListener = RemotingListener.V2Listener, RemotingClient = RemotingClient.V2Client)]
namespace Player.Interfaces
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This interface defines the methods exposed by an actor.
    /// Clients use this interface to interact with the actor that implements it.
    /// </summary>
    public interface IPlayer : IActor
    {
        Task<bool> JoinGameAsync(ActorId gameId, string playerName);
        Task<bool> MakeMoveAsync(ActorId gameId, int x, int y);
    }
}
```

Using Service Remoting V2, I can write client code and access the methods:

```
var player1 = ActorProxy.Create<IPlayer>(new ActorId("Player 1"), "fabric:/ActorWCFApplication");
```

How do I achieve the same using `WcfActorRemotingClientFactory` or WCF?

```
var wcfRemotingClient = new WcfActorRemotingClientFactory(WcfUtility.CreateTcpClientBinding(), null, 
                                     servicePartitionResolver: partitionResolver);
```

Any code snippet for WCF client code for Actor?